# Read textfile in Android - where to place the file

Tags: android, text-files, bufferedreader

Where do I place a certain textfile in the project of Eclipse if I want to read the contents?

Which objects should I use?

I tried with the following syntax but the file could not be found? Maybe the computers filesystem is used in this case?

```
 private void read() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File file = new File("test.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    String[] stringBuffer = new String[2];
    String line;
    int i = 0;
    while ( (line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {

        stringBuffer[i] = line;
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(stringBuffer[0] + stringBuffer[1]);
}
```

My idea was that the search begins in the rootfolder of the project but I guess its completely wrong because the computers filesystem is used?

Comment: what about using the `/assets` folder? or you can make a subfolder under it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to bundle this file with your Android application at build time, you have two choices: the `/raw` folder under `/res` or the `/assets` folder. You should place your file here and access it in the correct way for the chosen directory. For more information, read more about the built in folders for an Android project [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationProjects).

For an example, if you store your text file in `/assets/`, which is most likely the correct place for a text file, you need to access the contents of the file using `AssetManager`. Let's assume you created a file called:

```
/assets/test.txt
```

You can access the file as such, assuming that you are doing this from an Activity, so that the `this` keyword points to your Activity:

```
AssetManager assetManager = this.getResources().getAssets();
InputStream input = assetManager.open("test.txt");
```

You can now use that input stream to read from the file in a way similar to how you have done in your original question. You can use that InputStream to create a BufferedReader, as below, assuming your text content is encoded in UTF-8:

```
BufferedReader br = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: No problem @user3155478! Thanks @user2365568, I have fixed the variable reference.